# Como escrever uma data no tipo de ISO 8601

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Eu estou a fazer um programa de comunicação com apis online e eu estou a usar um header do tipo `DateTime` e eu precisava que essa data ficasse no tipo `ISO 8601` como posso fazer isso ?

Eu estou a usar isto para criar o header :

```
var tempo = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("teste");
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Date"+ tempo);
```

O output é este:

> Date2017-09-08T15:25:53Z

Eu queria que fosse este:

> Date: 2017-09-08T15:25:53Z

Comment: Editei a resposta, o que você queria era outra coisa.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");
```

ou

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm\\:ss.fffffffzzz");
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/115002/221800).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-stringsWT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Esta é forma de representação de um texto no formato especificado. Um `DateTime` não tem formato, é uma data é pronto, apenas textos possuem formato. Pela pergunta, inclusive a edição, o que deseja é um texto com a representação e não a data em si que é um número quantitativo.

Na verdade a pergunta é camaleoa, o que deseja de fato não é a data em formato ISO e sim construir o texto corretamente, assim:

```
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add($"Date: {DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")}");
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/7wlYWB). [E no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bQLvw3). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/FormatSpecific.cs).

Comment: como eu posso usar isso de maneira a que fique em DateTime ?

Comment: @PedroAzevedo editei a resposta pra te mostrar que isto não faz sentido.

Comment: recebi o seguinte erro : System.ArgumentException: 'O cabeçalho 'Date' tem de ser modificado com a propriedade ou o método adequado.'

Comment: Isto já é outro erro, você está modificando muito o que foi perguntado, abra outra pergunta sobre isto.

Comment: é um erro referente ao que postou na resposta

Comment: Não, a sua pergunta era sobre o formato da data, isto foi respondido e eu demostrei na reposta (até executando) que está como você especificou na pergunta, agora você tem um problema com a requisição. Este é outro problema completamente diferente.

Comment: muito obrigado na mesma eu vou efectuar outra pergunta

Answer (score 2):

**Opção 1:**

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");
```

**Opção 2:**

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm\\:ss.fffffffzzz");
```

**Opção 3** (com o formato usado especificado):

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
```

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-an-iso-8601-date-in-string-format)

Comment: como eu posso usar isso de maneira a que fique em DateTime ?

Comment: ISO 8601 é um padrão exibição (um formato de escrever a data), e não um "valor" em si. O mais próximo que você pode chegar para que fique em Datetime é `DateTime.UtcNow` e na hora que for exibir a data, chama o `ToString` igual a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tempo = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("teste");
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Date: "+ tempo);
```